# It's appropriated to use Duration, Period or YearMonth as class field type?

Tags: java, software-design

I have find some code when class fields are defined as `Duration`, `Period` or `YearMonth` rather than some date, time or datetime types or even primitives in the case of duration.

Those `java.time` classes seems to be more utilities that helps us to transform, convert and/or operate over a certain field but to store/retrieve it might be done by a more primitive/low-level available type.

On storage level I can see a duration like `PT60S` which is a standard to time-intervals but may not be widely adopted by all languages or databases. In case of data interchange or migration it can become a headache

In a NoSQL DB like mongo the value is stored as `String` but in a SQL DB one have to define a raw type and prepare a migration. Being a String is risk to store whatever someone wants.

What could be considered the best way to store such type of information to avoid mistakes and troubles in the future.

Examples of possible time interval approaches:

```
class TaskScheduler {         class TaskScheduler {
  String name;                  String name;
  Duration timeout;             Integer timeoutInSeconds;
  TaskStatus status;            TaskStatus status;
}                             }
```

Comment: @sleiman-jneidi do you still believe this question is opinion-based?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about Period, but Duration and YearMonth are both XML Schema simple types. I have not seen them used outside of that context.

> In my personal opinion those java.time classes are utilities that helps us to transform, convert and/or operate over a certain field but the storing/retrieving it might be done by a more primitive/low-level available type.

Possibly. Or maybe the ideal is a class that can represent the original value without any loss of information, and can also present itself as a primitive type when requested?

> Am I being too resistant to adopt latest APIs and loosing the advantage they are bringing to the table or is there actually a valid concern on this approach?

Based on the information that you have provided, I cannot say whether the code *should* be using those classes. The usual rules apply when it comes to rewriting somebody else's code. Be prepared to defend your decision with facts, and make sure that you don't fall into whatever traps that they were trying to avoid.

Comment: Hi @kimbert thanks for your answer,  I had to edit to be able to keep discussing it. To be honest I don't want to argue I am right or wrong but specially if those types are suitable to be used in a entity to be stored. One can have a very specialized type but I believe the concern is if it can be future-proof.